# How to write the SDP in cvx for the following optimization problem

Tags: convex-optimization, matlab, cvx

How to write the SDP(Semidefinite program) of the following optimization problem
\begin{multline}
\begin{aligned}
\max_{Z,f ,g} \ && trace(KZ) − f^Td  \\
\text{subject to}  && trace(W^{−1}Z) &= k && \\&&
Z_{ij} ≥ 0 \\
&& Z = Z^T  \\
&& Ze = Wf \\
&&e^Tf = (1 + α)n \\
&&e^T g ≥ (1 − β)n \\
&&f \geq g \\
&&0 \leq g \leq 1
\end{aligned}
\end{multline}

I have written the following code for the above optimization problem in the cvx matlab.

```
cvx_begin SDP
 variables Z(n_datapoints,n_datapoints) f(n_datapoints,1) g(n_datapoints,1)
 minimize ((f' * d ) - trace(K * Z))
 trace(inv(W) *  Z) == k_classes
 Z >= 0 
 Z == Z'
 (Z * e) == (W * f)
 e' * f == (1+alpha)*n_datapoints
 e'* g >= (1-beta)*n_datapoints
 f >= g
 g>= 0
 g <= 1
cvx_end
```

Above code is giving error in line "minimize ((f' * d ) * trace(K * Z))"
Error : "Error in . there is no other information showing.
"I am new in cvx. Can anyone help me why I am getting this error. Sorry for the bad indentation of the mathematical expression.

Comment: This really isn't a math question and as such doesn't belong here. But as luck would have it CVX has [its own support forum](http://ask.cvxr.com).

Comment: I agree with @MichaelGrant that this is question concerning the specifics of using a particular software, and as such is not math.

Comment: @MichaelGrant I would not agree, because we also have some Mathematica, Maple, MATLAB questions on MSE. I think questions about mathematical software /algorithms are also valid MSE questions. But that is just my point of view.